# Pig Json Multistorage?

Tags: json, hadoop, apache-pig

Using PIG (0.14), i'm interested in the following use-case: I wish to process my raw JSON into multiple output directories based upon their key and store the result (aggregated data) as JSON. The JSON has an evolving (dynamic) schema which is read in with elephant-bird, and (so-far) has not caused any problems.

I can either store the output in the correct directories (using MultiStorage) or as JSON (using JsonStorage) but not both. As far as i can tell, there is no publicly available UDF for this purpose.

Have I missed something, or is it just a case of writing my own UDF to perform this? This seems like a simple use-case and I would have thought would have been supported.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are looking for an answer to this; a UDF is required.

It is possible (and relatively straight forward) to combine the piggybank UDFs of JsonStorage and MultiStorage to create a pseudo "JsonMultiStorage" class.